# React-native: Requiring unknown module "./_castPath"

Tags: react-native

I just started getting this error today.  I'm not requiring that file and if I grep in my project directory for "castPath", nothing shows up so I'm not sure where this is actually happening.  Googling turned up nothing as well.

[image: error screenshot]

Comment: Did you try to do a `git bisect` do determine where to problem was introduced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  I was trying to run the project using a version of node different than what I had installed and built the packages with.

Needed to nuke my installed packages (`rm -rf ./node_modules`) and start again (`npm install`).